# C# read path withoutI put / in each subfolder

Tags: c#, file, path

I want to put file path in `File.Copy(path)`

How can I put the path and not add `/` every time?

In python I can put `r` to read the path and not add `/`:

```
open(r"path")
```

Is there anything similar in C Sharp?

Comment: Please give an example of input and desired output

Comment: Wait...........

Comment: Python 'r' for raw string equivalent in c# is '@'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the `@` operator: `var path = @"c:\\APath\bier";`

these are called verbatim strings:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#regular-and-verbatim-string-literals

Edit:

Also when dealing with paths string interpolation may come in handy, in short its a way to substitute values in a string. Its the same as `string.format` but the syntax is better imo:

```cs
var hello = "Hello";
var world = "world";

var helloworldStringFormat = string.Format("{0} {1}", hello, world);

var helloworldStringInterpolation = $"{hello} {world}";
```

Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-interpolation

Any ways you can do things like this:

```
var someValue = "bier";
var path3 = $"c:\\APath\\{someValue}";
var path4 = string.Format(@"c:\APath\{0}", someValue);
```

Also check out the `Path` class for dealing with paths, and optionally the `Directory` class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-5.0